# Stop truncation/rounding off

Tags: formatting, openoffice-calc

In OpenOffice Calc (spreadsheet) when I copy and paste a content in the cell it gets rounded off with three decimal places and the values get truncated with 000 in the end.

e.g. If I paste `9104984638383554567` the value gets converted to `9104984638383550000`.

I have tried formatcells->changed the cell/column type as TEXT also but it didn't work. I don't want to lose data.

Answer (score 0):

Your pasted value exceeds the precision to which most OpenOffice Calc implementations retain and present values.

It should retain text of that length.  However, you won't be able to calculate with the numeric value of that text at its full precision.

Try giving the value a leading ' character to see if it then retains the full text.

Comment: But how is that possible if i am extracting data from a script ?